# Weird problem with Guake and Terminator

Tags: 16.04, command-line, keyboard, terminator, guake

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Guake was working normally without having any issue.

But since yesterday the backspace and Left and Down arrow keys are not working as it supposed to be...

Also before pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> would take me to a clear screen on the left but now with the same combo, it is coming in the center.

while pressing backspace key there is a space between character and keep pressing it displaying some weird character.
I am very confused on what may be the issue.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Comment: I'm having the same issue using Terminator.

Comment: The problem is fixed by uninstalling and re-installing back after a couple of times, but I did not find out the reason that caused this issue.